# Can a missing table cause no error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to clear out a lot of clutter in various databases on a SQL Server that were left behind by some sloppy prior employees. My boss is afraid to let me delete  unused tables because he believes it might not generate an error message, but might simply cause wrong data to be returned. I don't see how; if a table is joined in a SQL statement and the table doesn't exist, I can't imagine it not raising an error. Is this possible?

Comment: Of course a missing table causes an error.  The thing to do is to rename the table and see if there are any errors -- then you can rename them back.

Comment: what if there was a try catch that returned a default value - furthermore someone could write SQL to check for a table's existence, then do something different if it is not there - so your boss is right that almost anything, could in theory, happen - I'm imagining stored procedures though, not single SQL statement execution

Comment: If you're talking about raw SQL, you'll get an error. If you're talking about some app that hits the database remotely, then who knows -- the app could have been written (intentionally or otherwise) to silently ignore database errors.

Comment: Maybe you can rename the table(s). If the app continues to work without error for some time, *then* delete it.

Comment: Perhaps since your boss clearly doesn't really understand databases he/she should entrust the details to somebody like yourself who knows what they are doing.

Comment: There are contrived situations where this would be possible, like having a name resolve to an object in a different scheme, or code that explicitly catches errors from dynamic SQL but then proceeds with empty results. Typically, however, you're much more worried about wrongly deeming a table to be unused and seeing errors from code that happens to use it than you would be about silently changed results.

Comment: Start source controlling your database schema. Store old structure. Remove tables you believe are redundant. If testing exposes problems, you can always find the structure again and reintroduce it. (Of course, if the tables have data, you'll have to separately deal with storing that before you drop the table). "We shouldn't delete (code/structure/data) because *something* might be using it" is a *weak* approach to take and it should be recognized that such an approach will just let clutter build up again.

Comment: That's the way I look at it, Damien. Sloppy programming and practices by prior employees has made my boss worried that anything can go wrong, no matter how impossible it seems.

Answer (score 1):

In normal circumstance you'd always get an error, however these may not be normal circumstances.

It's unlikely, but if you have procedures building dynamic SQL using the information_schema views to get table names you could potentially write some SQL that fails silently if the table isn't there

Comment: All the answers so far reinforce what I believe. First of all, I would rename the table(s) before deleting them, just in case. But we don't have any applications or SQL statements that use Try...Catch or anything to bypass or ignore errors, we don't use any stored procedures, we just run queries against tables to generate reports etc. It's a small shop with about 25 employees and only 3 or 4 of us write anything that touches the database, so it's easy to ask around if anyone knows any reason not to delete a table. I do think my boss is being overly cautious.

Comment: Is there any data in these tables? maybe the best solution is to archive them

Comment: Hi Dave...what I'm thinking is to rename the table and see if anything goes wrong. We do have the the drives the data is on backed up, in case of catastrophe.

Answer (score 1):

It's technically possible depending on how you access the data and how any stored procedures querying said table were written. E.g. if there are TRY CATCH blocks in your T-SQL, it could be possible. But that's just theoretical. In practice, you'll get real ugly errors if you delete a table.

What I would do in the interim is rename the table and then run every unit test and integration test you can find. If something references the table, rename it back to what it was, otherwise dump it.